# Webpack Build SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babel-loader

Note: I read through the other similar questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42288792/webpack-syntaxerror-unexpected-token) and others), but they are all about earlier versions of webpack and babel and do not solve the following issue.

This is serving just fine, but when I run `npm run build` I'm getting the following error. How do I solve this?  (And how do I get better errors than this?, the log is just as bad).

```
> react_01@1.0.0 build /Users/monkeydo/Documents/code/__tests/react_01
> webpack --mode production

/Users/monkeydo/Documents/code/__tests/react_01/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:41
                )} manually.`,
                ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at runCli (/Users/monkeydo/Documents/code/__tests/react_01/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js:69:2)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react_01@1.0.0 build: `webpack --mode production`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the react_01@1.0.0 build script.
```

My webpack file looks like this:

```
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')

module.exports = {
  //entry: ['@babel/polyfill', './src/index.js'],
  entry: './src/index.js',
  // Where files should be sent once they are bundled
 output: {
   path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
   filename: 'index.bundle.js'
 },
  // webpack 5 comes with devServer which loads in development mode
 devServer: {
   port: 3000,
   watchContentBase: true
 },
  // Rules of how webpack will take our files, complie & bundle them for the browser
 module: {
   rules: [
     {
       test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      // test: /\.jsx?/,
       exclude: /nodeModules/,
       use: {
         loader: 'babel-loader',
         query:
           {
             presets:['react', 'preset-env']
           }
       }
     },
     {
       test: /\.css$/,
       use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader']
     }
   ]
 },
 plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: './src/index.html' }), new MiniCssExtractPlugin()]
}
```

My package json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "react_01",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.jsx",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "webpack serve --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.7",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "css-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.2",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack": "^5.45.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  }
```

My babelrc file looks like this:

```
{
  "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react"
  ]
}
```

My index.js file looks like this:

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDom from "react-dom"
import App from "./components/app"
import "./style.css"

ReactDom.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

My app.js file looks like this:

```
import React from "react"

function App() {
    return (<div>
        <h2>Welcome to My new React App</h2>
        <h3>Date : {new Date().toDateString()}</h3>
    </div>)
}

export default App
```

*** Edit: not sure what I was thinking... I totally forgot to add the webpack code before :o ! I guess that was a dyslexic senior moment. It's added now.

Comment: What version of Node are you using? Does your code editor show any errors when you open the incriminated file? Have you tried deleting your node_modules and reinstalling them?

Comment: @Altareos node v16.5.0 , no errors in the code editor.  Yes I've tried deleting the node_modules folder and reinstalling. I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the styles import

import "./style.css"

Webpack speaks JavaScript, not css, if you want it to learn it you need to create a webpack config file and use the proper loader to handle css

Comment: Thanks, you reminded me to actually add the webpack code to the above, which somehow I completely forgot to do when I first posted this :o !